# How to prove that $f^{-1}(B)\subset A \Rightarrow B \subset f(A)$ if and only if $f$ is surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

so I'm trying to prove that $f^{-1}(B)\subset A \Rightarrow B \subset f(A)$ if and only if f is surjective. I'm used to proving proofs with just one implication, but now I'm confused because of the "if and only if" statement. I will show you the actual question and show you what I know. I hope someone can help me, because I'm clueless for the moment.

#### Question

$$\forall A \in P(X): \forall B \in P(Y): f^{-1}(B) \subset A \Longrightarrow B \subset f(A) \text{ if and only if $f$ is surjective}$$

#### What I know

- $P(X)$ is the powerset = is the set of all subsets of $X$
- Inverse image: If $K$ is a subset of $Y$ and $f^{-1}(K)$ is a subset of $X$ given by: $f^{-1}(K)=\{x\in 
  X|f(x)\in K\}$
- If $A\subset B$ = "every element in A is also an element of B"
- surjective =  $\forall y\in Y|\exists x\in X: f(x)=y $

If someone knows the answer it would be very kind to share your wisdom :)

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show two things. (1) If $f$ is surjective, $A\subseteq X$, $B\subseteq Y$, and $f^{-1}[B]\subseteq A$, then $B\subseteq f[A]$. (2) If $B\subseteq f[A]$ whenever $A\subseteq X$, $B\subseteq Y$, and $f^{-1}[B]\subseteq A$, then $f$ is surjective. I recommend starting with (1).

Comment: Where $f$ is...???

Comment: what is the definition of surjective maps?

Comment: for a function to be surjective each element of the codomain must be mapped at least ones @crystal_math

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks for answering, but I don't quite understand your reasoning

Comment: @TheCreator: There really isn’t much reasoning involved: I simply expanded the statement of the problem to make it easier to understand. What I wrote says exactly the same thing as the problem; it just states the two directions of the *if and only if* separately. My (1) is the implication $\Leftarrow$, and my (2) is the implication $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: ah wow I see, I think the first part is doable, but how could you prove the second part? any tips? And thanks again for answering

Comment: @TheCreator Now what is the definition of $f(A)$?

Comment: If A is a subset of X and f(a) is a subset given by: $$f(a)=\{y\in Y|x \in A :f(x) = y\}$$

Comment: ow I see, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider function $f\colon X \to Y$ and consider definition of [surjective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) as: $f(X)=Y$ i.e. $\forall y \in Y, \exists x \in X, y=f(x)\quad (1)$.

Now let's take your sentence $f^{-1}(B)\subset A \Rightarrow B \subset f(A)$ for $\forall A \subset X$, $\forall B \subset Y\quad (2)$.

If holds $(2)$, taking $B=Y$ and $A=X$, obviously gives surjectivity.

Now assume $(1)$ and let's take any such $A,B$, that $f^{-1}(B)\subset A$. If we take $y \in B$, then as $B \subset Y$ and function is surjective we have, that $\exists x \in X, y=f(x)\in B$. From last we have $x \in f^{-1}(B) \subset A$, so $x \in A$, so $y=f(x) \in f(A)$.